# Node.js: process.argv vs. process.ARGV

Tags: javascript, process, node.js, argv

I notice that Node defines both `process.argv` and `process.ARGV` (capitalized). The later isn't mentioned in the documentation and is, in every case I've encountered so far, the same object.

Is `ARGV` just a historic holdover, or does it have a purpose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`process.ARGV` has been [removed entirely](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/08cb8fce6737262a6817716976be1536a8fbd0b6) since `v0.5.10`.

Comment: Can't argue with commits. :)

Answer (score 4):

They are identical:

node.cc

```
// process.argv
Local<Array> arguments = Array::New(argc - option_end_index + 1);
arguments->Set(Integer::New(0), String::New(argv[0]));
for (j = 1, i = option_end_index; i < argc; j++, i++) {
  Local<String> arg = String::New(argv[i]);
  arguments->Set(Integer::New(j), arg);
}
// assign it
process->Set(String::NewSymbol("ARGV"), arguments);
process->Set(String::NewSymbol("argv"), arguments);
```

**Edit** (based on further question):

There's only one person who can tell you that for *sure* (the author) - you might be able to find him on IRC (`irc.freenode.net #node.js`).

Looking through the other symbols, I'd guess that it was added for consistency - `argv` and `env` seem to be the only two that have both lower and upper case versions. However, `ENV` differs *slightly* from `env`. Maybe the author thought that `argv` and `ARGV` might differ in the same manner as `env` and `ENV`?

Comment: node warns you every time you use process.ENV: `Use process.env instead of process.ENV`. Presumably these are deprecated but kept for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @ricardo: cool, didn't dig that far through the source.. +1 :)

Comment: I just remembered seeing that message :) turns out they are really deprecated: http://github.com/joyent/node/pull/372

Comment: It is easy to get this confused, especially if you ever use spidermonkey. `gjs` uses `ARGV` and not `process.argv`. Fun fact.